# code igniter form_dropdown() order

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to order the dropdown items in alphabetical order but am unable to do so. I must be missing something obvious..

I assumed `ORDER BY type_name` would have created the array in alphabetical order

```
$data['training_types'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM training_types ORDER BY type_name")->result_array();

print_r($training_types);
foreach ($training_types as $type)
{
    $options[$type['id']] = $type['type_name'];
    echo $options[$type['id']]; //test only: this displays the options in alphabetical order just fine
}
print_r($options);
echo form_dropdown('training_type',$options,'0');
//for some reason when the dropdown is created, the order is not alphabetical, it's not even ordered by id... I have no idea what is ordering it this way.
```

1st print_r returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [type_name] => Independent Study ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [type_name] => Instructor Lead ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [type_name] => Instructor Lead/Virtual ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 7 [type_name] => Job Aid ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [type_name] => Mentoring ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 2 [type_name] => Virtual ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 4 [type_name] => Web ) )
```

2nd print_r returns:

```
Array ( [2] => Virtual [3] => Instructor Lead/Virtual [4] => Web [1] => Instructor Lead [5] => Mentoring [6] => Independent Study [7] => Job Aid )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you `print_r($data['training_types'])` before the `foreach` loop and `print_r($options)` after the loop, and post results? This will help give insight as to what is going into the loop and what is coming out, to make sure it isn't the Form Helper `form_dropdown()` isn't reordering anything.

My suggestion is to just add a simple `asort($options);` before the `form_dropdown()` to insure it is alphabetical.

Comment: good point. It appears form_dropdown() isn't the culprit. Printing $options shows that it is messed up before it gets to generating the dropdown. See original post for print results.

Comment: Maybe just a simple `asort($options);` before the `form_dropdown()` to confirm it is alphabetical.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether it's Ascending or Descending.

`ORDER BY type_name ASC` or `ORDER BY type_name DESC`

Comment: If it is MySQL, the default behavior of `ORDER BY` is to order the records in ascending order.

Comment: it is SQLite. Adding ASC doesn't appear to make any difference. The same order results.